# Consuming Queue with EM-HTTP : unable to create new socket: Too many open files

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, eventmachine

I have a ruby processes that consume msgs from a RabbitMQ queue using amqp gem, something like this :

```rb
require "bundler/setup"
require "amqp"
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'


AMQP.start(:host => $AMQP_URL) do |connection|
  @channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  @queue   ||= @channel.queue("results")

  puts " [*] Waiting for messages. "

  @queue.subscribe do |body|    
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(URL).post :body => body          

    http.callback {
      # do something
    }        

    http.errback  { 
      $LOG.error "[errorback] -> #{http.error}"    
    }
  end
end
```

Now the URL is slow, and the queue has so much messages ( > 30K ), I got this error in the log:

```
**[errorback] -> unable to create new socket: Too many open files**
```

Any help would be highly appreciated since I've been trying all my time figuring out how to solve it but with no results at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that I'm using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are consuming the messages too fast. Since you basically fetch all undelivered messages at once (i.e. as fast as RabbitMQ can deliver them), and open an HTTP connection for each message, you end up consuming all available resources of your system (in this case the number of parallel open sockets).

After reading docs on [message acknowledgements](http://rdoc.info/gems/amqp/file/docs/Queues.textile#Message_acknowledgements) and [`AMQP::Queue#subscribe`](http://rdoc.info/gems/amqp/AMQP/Queue%3asubscribe)), I'd propose these changes to your code:

```rb
AMQP.start(host: $AMQP_URL) do |connection|
  @channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  @channel.prefetch(5) 
  @queue ||= @channel.queue("results")

  # disable auto-ack, switch to manual mode
  @queue.subscribe(ack: true) do |meta, body|
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(URL).post body: body          

    http.callback {
      # do something

      # acknowledge message consumption
      meta.ack
    }

    http.errback {
      # ...
      # do not `meta.ack` here, so the message gets redelivered
    }
  end
end
```

This way, you can throttle your workload quite easily.